# как поставить выпадающие списки в ряд?

Tags: html, css, list

я решил сделать 3 списка, в которых будет определённое описание, но при попытках поставить их в один ряд(лево-право), ничего не получается

```html
<div class="info">
  <details> текст </details>
  <details> текст </details>
  <details> текст </details>
</div>
```

что надо сделать, чтобы все получилось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> но при попытках поставить их в один ряд(лево-право), ничего не получается

Можно предложить такой вариант...

```css
.info {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
.info details {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <details> текст </details>
  <details> текст </details>
  <details> текст </details>
</div>
```

Или вот так...

```css
.info {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: start;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 10px;
}
.info details {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <details> текст </details>
  <details> текст </details>
  <details> текст </details>
</div>
```

Comment: помогло. можно ли текст внутри расположить по середине?

Comment: @2SeeD, добавил еще стилей...

Comment: Спасибо! не мог найти ответ два дня

Comment: появилась еще одна проблема. при открытии списка, все другие двигаются

Comment: @2SeeD, значит тебе нужно делать более подробный тестовый пример...